# Is referencing JS values by variable different from referencing by literal value for JSON parsing purposes?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm having some issues with the Facebook JS SDK here, http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10243785/fb-ui-call-throws-json-parsing-error-serializing-then-deserializing-input-ob, but I'm posing it as a more generic JSON question here.

If I were to serialize the following javascript values into JSON strings, is there any circumstance or any parsers that would treat them differently? I'd be especially interested if there would be any parser that would fail to stringify the b version.

```
var value = {"value":"one"};
var a = {"data1":{"value":"one"},"data2":{"value":"one"}};
var b = {"data1":value,"data2":value};
```

Comment: Why would a JavaScript parser be creating JSON strings? This makes no sense. The JavaScript parser parses your code, some objects are created (that don't care what the code looked like that created them). The objects can be serialized as JSON.

Comment: If you want to pass the content between pages or servers, you're going to have to serialize it.

Comment: Think about what I'm saying. Why would the JSON serializer, which deals with objects, care what the JavaScript that created those objects looked like?

Comment: Oh okay, I misinterpreted your question at first.

That's exactly my line of thinking as well. A JSON serializer should not care that a and b in my example are defined differently, it's just supposed to render the values into strings and those values are the same.

BUT, in my real world application (dealing with FB js sdk), their code is throwing an error on b above. If I give it a, it passes. Thus I ask this question.

Comment: Why don't you test whether the browser stringifies both objects as you expect without trying to do any facebook stuff... if it works, the problem is with FB.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in my JS console and both the above examples, and the input I give to Facebook stringify just fine (using JSON.stringify()). So I'm fairly sure the problem is Facebook, I just wanted to validate that my examples aren't doing anything wrong, and maybe investigate if there are known quirks or odd behaviors with certain JSON serialization implementations out there. Thanks for your comments, it really helps my sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik: the default JSON parser of modern browsers are 'stringifying' the b example correct, so the reference to `value` is stringified too.

```
console.log('a: '+JSON.stringify(a));
console.log('b: '+JSON.stringify(b));
/* all browsers I know (for IE restriction is IE>7) show
a: {"data1":{"value":"one"},"data2":{"value":"one"}} 
b: {"data1":{"value":"one"},"data2":{"value":"one"}}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience JSON parsers won't fail for any of your examples.
The main threat for a JSON parser are cyclic references such as :

```
var object = {};
object.value = object;
```

which you don't seem to have.